# Pythonでの複数ある辞書の比較について

Tags: python

値の左から順に同じグループになります。例えば、group1では、Aのaの1が一つのグループで、また別に、Bのaの2のグループ、Cのbの1のグループ、Dのaの1のグループとなり、4つのグループが存在することになります。

```
dict1 = {"group1":["A","B","C","D"],"group2":["E","F","G","H","I"],"group3":["J","K","L","M","N"]}
dict2 = {"group1":["a","a","b","a"],"group2":["a","a","a","a","a"],"group3":["a","a","a","b","b"]}
dict3 = {"group1":["1","2","1","1"],"group2":["1","1","2","3","4"],"group3":["1","1","2","2","2"]}
```

以下がdict1,dict2,dict3という辞書に対して行いたい処理です。

1. それぞれのgroupの中で値を照合
2. 違う種類がどれくらいあるか判別（group１の中では、aの1は2つあり、aの2は1つ、bの1は1つなので、3種類存在する）し、それぞれのグループごとにアルファベットの大文字を書き出す。
3. 結果を立て並びに出力する

以下のように出力したいです。

```
result = 
4       #何種類あるか示します
group2
a  1  E,F     #dict2,dict3,dict1の情報を示します
a  2  G
a  3  H
a  4  I

3       
group1
a 　1　 A,D
a 　2 　B
b 　1 　C

group3
a 　1　 J,K
a 　2 　L
b 　2 　M,N
```

知識不足ながらプログラム案を考えてみましたが、種類が大きい順に示すこととグループごとに大文字アルファベットを示すことができません。ご教示お願い致します。

```
set_list = {k: len(set(zip(dict2[k], dict3[k]))) for k in dict2.keys()}
result = []
for r in set_list.keys():
  result.append(set_list[r])
  result.append(list(set(zip(dict2[r], dict3[r]))))
  result.append(dict1[r])

#出力
[3, [('a', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('b', '1')], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 4, [('a', '3'), ('a', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('a', '4')], ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], 3, [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('a', '2')], ['J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N']]
```

Comment: 議論が続いたため、その部分のコメントを[チャットへ移動させました](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143210/discussion-on-question-by--python)。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

itertools の groupby を使う方法。

```py
from itertools import groupby

dict1 = {"group1":["A","B","C","D"],"group2":["E","F","G","H","I"],"group3":["J","K","L","M","N"]}
dict2 = {"group1":["a","a","b","a"],"group2":["a","a","a","a","a"],"group3":["a","a","a","b","b"]}
dict3 = {"group1":["1","2","1","1"],"group2":["1","1","2","3","4"],"group3":["1","1","2","2","2"]}

keyfunc = lambda x: x[:2]
result = [(g, {k: [i[-1] for i in v]
              for k, v in groupby(sorted(zip(dict2[g], dict3[g], dict1[g]), key=keyfunc), key=keyfunc)})
          for g in dict1.keys()]
result.sort(key=lambda i: len(i[1]), reverse=True)

for g in result:
    print(len(g[1]))
    print(g[0])
    for i, j in g[1].items():
        print(*i, ','.join(j), sep='\t')
    print()

# 4
# group2
# a 1   E,F
# a 2   G
# a 3   H
# a 4   I
# 
# 3
# group1
# a 1   A,D
# a 2   B
# b 1   C
# 
# 3
# group3
# a 1   J,K
# a 2   L
# b 2   M,N
```

Answer (score 2):

groupby 使う方法

```py
dict1 = {"group1":["A","B","C","D"],"group2":["E","F","G","H","I"],"group3":["J","K","L","M","N"]}
dict2 = {"group1":["a","a","b","a"],"group2":["a","a","a","a","a"],"group3":["a","a","a","b","b"]}
dict3 = {"group1":["1","2","1","1"],"group2":["1","1","2","3","4"],"group3":["1","1","2","2","2"]}

from itertools import groupby
g_key = lambda v: v[1:]
for k in dict1:
    res = [(k2, ','.join(u for u,*_ in g))
            for k2,g in groupby(sorted(zip(dict1[k], dict2[k], dict3[k]), key=g_key), key=g_key)]

    print(len(res))
    print(k)
    for item in res:
        print(f'{item[0][0]}\t{item[0][1]}\t{item[1]}')
```

Answer (score 1):

dict2,3値をキーとし、それに対応するdict1値をリストに格納することで、求める結果を得ることができます。

```
dict1 = {"group1":["A","B","C","D"],"group2":["E","F","G","H","I"],"group3":["J","K","L","M","N"]}
dict2 = {"group1":["a","a","b","a"],"group2":["a","a","a","a","a"],"group3":["a","a","a","b","b"]}
dict3 = {"group1":["1","2","1","1"],"group2":["1","1","2","3","4"],"group3":["1","1","2","2","2"]}

for key in dict1.keys():

    # 2,3の値をキーとし、それに対応する1の値をリストに格納
    sub_d = {}
    for d1, d2, d3 in zip(dict1[key], dict2[key], dict3[key]):
        sub_k = (d2, d3)
        if sub_k not in sub_d:
            sub_d[sub_k] = []
        sub_d[sub_k].append(d1)

    # 結果の出力
    print(len(sub_d))
    print(key)
    for k, v in sub_d.items():
        print(k[0], k[1], *v)
"""
3
group1
a 1 A D
a 2 B
b 1 C
4
group2
a 1 E F
a 2 G
a 3 H
a 4 I
3
group3
a 1 J K
a 2 L
b 2 M N
"""
```